# Using paste() within t.test() in user defined R function

Tags: r, function, user-defined

I am trying to write a function which accepts `Var1` and `Var2` from user and run the `t.test` and return the mean for female classification. But I am getting an error for the calc line. If I run the program without the paste and `as.formula` functions and run with `t.test(dat[[Var2]]~dat[[Var1]]` I will get the correct answer.

But in my original code I am required to use the paste function. Could anyone let me know what is the mistake in the code below using paste and as.formula functions? I am using the quine dataframe from MASS library.

```
func = function(dat=quine,Var1,Var2){
  # calc = t.test(dat[[Var2]]~dat[[Var1]] #gives the answer
  calc = t.test(as.formula(paste(dat[[Var2]], dat[[Var1]], sep="~"))) #gives an error
  return(F.mean = calc$estimate[1])
}

func(Var1= "Sex", Var2= "Days")
```

Here is the head(quine)

```
Eth Sex Age Lrn Days
```

`1   A   M  F0  SL    2`

`2   A   M  F0  SL   11`

`3   A   M  F0  SL   14`

`4   A   M  F0  AL    5`

`5   A   M  F0  AL    5`

`6   A   M  F0  AL   13`

Comment: Can you post a sample dataset using `dput(quine)`? Or if the data frame is too big, `dput(head(quine, 20))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
func <- function(dat = quine, Var1, Var2){
  calc = t.test(as.formula(paste("dat[[Var2]]", "dat[[Var1]]", sep = "~"))) 
  return(F.mean = calc$estimate[1])
}

func(Var1 = "Sex", Var2 = "Days")
```

Note the difference between pasting a string and an object.

Answer (score 0):

In the function include the code line

```
print(paste(dat[[Var2]], dat[[Var1]], sep="~"))
```

to see what is wrong. `paste` pastes each element of the vector `dat[[Var1]]` with each element of the vector `dat[[Var2]]`. The result is a vector of length `nrow(dat)`. Then, only the *first* element is coerced to `formula`. And only that one is used by `t.test`.

The correct code would be (note the `data` argument):

```
func = function(dat=quine,Var1,Var2){
  # calc = t.test(dat[[Var2]]~dat[[Var1]] #gives the answer
  calc = t.test(as.formula(paste(Var2, Var1, sep="~")), data = dat)
  return(c(F.mean = unname(calc$estimate[1])))
}
```

Note also how the `return` instruction has changed.

Though we don't have sample data to test the function, we can make up something.

```
set.seed(8294)
n <- 100
quine <- data.frame(Sex = sample(c("M", "F"), n, TRUE), Days = runif(n))

func(Var1= "Sex", Var2= "Days")
#   F.mean 
#0.5100037
```

Comment: Thank you. The unname() function helped in another section of the code.